# Algorithm to combine two arrays for the smallest CQL filter

Tags: javascript, typescript, algorithm, query-optimization, cql

I have an array of `tables` containing an array of `privilege_ids`. I create CQL filters with the ids like `(((table_id in (1,2,3)) and (privilege_id in ('abc','def','ghi'))) and ((table_id in (4,5)) and (privilege_id in ('def','ghi','jkl'))))`.

So I need an algorithm that finds the best grouping of `table_id` and `privilege_id` to get the shortest CQL out of it.

Input Tables

```
[
  { id: 1, privilege_ids: ['abc','def','ghi', 'mno', ..., 'yza'] },
  { id: 2, privilege_ids: ['abc','def','ghi', 'mno', ..., 'yza'] },
  { id: 3, privilege_ids: ['abc','def','ghi', 'mno', ..., 'yza'] },
  { id: 4, privilege_ids: ['def','ghi','jkl', 'mno', ..., 'yza'] },
  { id: 5, privilege_ids: ['def','ghi','jkl', 'mno', ..., 'yza'] }
]
```

Output

```
[
   { table_ids: [1, 2, 3], privilege_ids: ['abc'] },
   { table_ids: [4, 5], privilege_ids: ['jkl'] },
   { table_ids: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], privilege_ids: ['def','ghi', 'mno', ..., 'yza'] }
]
```

The output is used to create the CQL. In this example you can also group `1, 2, 3` and `4, 5`. However the overlapping `privilege_ids` would create more text than the additional grouping of table_ids `1,2,3,4,5`. So this is the algorithm I need.

There are around 1 - 10 tables per query with each 1 - 500 privilege_ids. Most of the privilege_ids overlap. The goal is to find the biggest overlapping `privilege_id` combination with their `table_id` to create the smallest CQL filter in extreme cases (500 privilege_ids) without making it to big for smaller usecases (10 privilege_ids).

Comment: The language is not that important. I added some input and output to clarify what kind of algorithm I need. I hope this makes it clear.

Comment: Looks a *minimum cover* problem.

Comment: (Took a guess tagging CQL - please remove if not about *Cassandra Query Language* or that is unlikely to be instrumental in useful answers.)